# ServiceStack 4.0.60: How to modify/kill sessions if the default behaviour is to not persist them to cache?

Tags: session, authentication, caching, servicestack

In my existing application I am able to log out (destroy) sessions because I keep a list of session Id's associated to a user. This would allow me to provide functionality like "log out all other sessions" for a user. After upgrading to ServiceStack v4.0.60 this won't work as the default behaviour is to not persist the sessions in the cache server side.

In the [change log for release v4.0.60](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/docs/2016/v4.0.60.md#v4060-release-notes) I found the following:

> By default all `IAuthWithRequest` Auth Providers no longer persist the Users >Session in the Cache, the result of which requires each of the above Auth >Providers to resend their Credentials / Auth Info on every request, as was >already the current and expected behavior in all Service Clients which >supported these Authentication options.
>
> Previously only the **First** Request required sending Auth Info, as any subsequent >requests could access the previously established **Authenticated Session**.

**So how can I modify/remove Sessions if they're not persisted in cache and I'm not currently handling a request originating from that session?**

Or would I be better off re-enabling persistence in the registered `IAuthProvider`s instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the default behavior of `IAuthWithRequest` AuthProviders wont persist sessions since they **re-authenticate** with every request which sets up a new Session and never gets to use their existing Session anyway.

This change only prevents the following Auth Providers from persisting User Sessions:

- BasicAuthProvider
- DigestAuthProvider
- AspNetWindowsAuthProvider

And the 2 new Auth Providers added in the latest release:

- ApiKeyAuthProvider
- JwtAuthProvider

All other Auth Providers (i.e. that don't re-authenticate with every request) remains unchanged.

> So how can I modify/remove Sessions if they're not persisted in cache and I'm not currently handling a request originating from that session?

Removing Sessions of the above Auth Providers doesn't have any effect since they authenticate with every request which creates a new Session. So the change is now they no longer persist the User Session they never end up using.

Comment: Thanks for the fast and clear answer! I was confused as we mainly use the CredentialsAuthProvider which I just learned is not affected by this behaviour. The reason I had issues is because my NUnit tests use the JsonServiceClient which (I assume) uses the BasicAuthProvider and therefore failed some session-related tests.